# Rendering Highcharts Chart in Two Container

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/4ghhf/614/) and let me know how I can render one highcharts chart into two container
I already tried both

```
renderTo: 'container',
renderTo: 'container2',
```

and

```
renderTo: 'container, container2',
```

in

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'column',
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'useHTML = true',
                useHTML: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [23,45,12,89,123,12,5]}]

    });

});
```

but no success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ID's you should call highcharts on classname. I have added a fake class (render_here) to make it work. use it like below code :

```
$(function() {
$('.render_here').each(function(){
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: this,

        type: 'column',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'useHTML = true',
            useHTML: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [23,45,12,89,123,12,5]}]

});
});
});
```

Here is the [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4ghhf/615/)